# Oracle ADF patch

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf

We are getting XML http errors while closing the chrome browser, so for that we are trying to apply the Adf bundle Patch and see if any pom.xml files or any libraries are changing. We need to apply a patch for Jdeveloper 12c, we need the steps to apply Opatch for windows.
Can anyone one help on how to apply patch or any alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

The read.me file inside the bundle patch has detailed instructions on how to apply the patch.
What exactly is the problem?

Comment: In readme file only the steps and commands for Linux are mentioned, but we need the steps for applying in windows.

Comment: For windows you use the same instructions. the OPATCH folder has a opatch.bat file that is used in windows systems.